# How draw a rectangle directly on an image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, pixel, drawimage

[image]

I want to draw a rectangle on the actual image and don't want to use the flutter renderer to add a rectangle on the top layer just as a view. I can get the pixel color, but how can I overwrite the bonch of pixels?

```
    ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/maps/map.jpg');
    Uint8List bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    List<int> values = bytes;
    img.Image photo = img.decodeImage(values)!;
    final pixels = photo.getBytes(format: img.Format.rgba);
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m not quite sure, if this is the answer you need, but what about using a Stack?

```
Stack(children: [
         image,
         Positioned.fill(
            child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: Sky(r), 
                    child: Container()));
                    }),
                ],
)
...


class Sky extends CustomPainter {
  Rect rect;

  Sky(this.rect);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint()..color = Colors.black);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Sky oldDelegate) => false;
}
```